how to set map scale with tmap in r?
I'm struggling to change the scale of my map using the tmap package. I've attempted to adjust various parameters using the 'scale' argument in the tmap_save function, but it seems that this doesn't resolve my issue.
As you can see from comparing the two maps, the second one appears smaller than the one on the top, despite both maps having the same cell size. At the end, it looks like the size of the cells of the second map is smaller compared to the other one. This discrepancy is due to the fact that the second city is significantly larger than the other one. Therefore, I've been trying to find a way to make the larger city appear bigger on the map. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
This is the code I used to create the two maps
tm_shape(shapefile) + 
tm_borders() + 
tm_layout(frame = F) 
tmap_save(shapefile, "shapefile.png",height = 11.27, width = 14.69)


Note that in this example, the scale is not exactly the same across the entire area of both maps, but this is true for almost all maps given the distortions inherent to CRS projections. However, the y-axis/latitude distance is the same for both plots.
The workflow:

create extent points from largest city bounding box (bbox) and calculate difference in decimal degrees of min and max longitude and latitude values
offset centroid coordinates of smallest city using values from Step 1, and create new 'plot extent' sf object (bb)

The example data used in this repex have a CRS of NAD27/EPSG:4267. As such, this code will throw a warning, which you can safely ignore.
Step 0: Load required packages and create example data
library(tmap)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

# Example data for making small and large sf objects
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

# Example small city
sf_small <- filter(nc, NAME == "Lee") %>%
  st_make_grid(cellsize = .05) %>%
  st_as_sf()

# Example large city
sf_large <- filter(nc, NAME == "Dare") %>%
  st_make_grid(cellsize = .05) %>%
  st_as_sf()

Step 1: Get difference between min and max lon/lat decimal degrees for largest city
# Function to create polygon from bounding box
bbox_poly <- function(x) {
  bb <- sf::st_bbox(x)
  
  p <- matrix(
    c(bb["xmin"], bb["ymin"], 
      bb["xmin"], bb["ymax"],
      bb["xmax"], bb["ymax"], 
      bb["xmax"], bb["ymin"], 
      bb["xmin"], bb["ymin"]),
    ncol = 2, byrow = T
  )
  
  sf::st_polygon(list(p))
}

# Get points coordinates for sf_large extent
box <- st_sfc(bbox_poly(sf_large)) %>%
  st_set_crs(st_crs(sf_large)) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_cast("POINT") %>%
  distinct() %>%
  st_coordinates()

# # Get lon/lat decimal degrees difference
lon_diff <- as.numeric(abs(box[1,1] - box[4,1]))
lat_diff <- as.numeric(abs(box[1,2] - box[2,2]))

Step 2: Offset centroid coordinates of smallest city using values from from Step 1 and create polygon sf from resultant coordinates
# Get centroid coordinates of sf_small
sf_small_cent <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(sf_small), crs = st_crs(sf_small)) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_centroid() %>%
  st_coordinates()

# Create bbox for extent of sf_small tmap() plot by offsetting sf_small centroid
bb <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = sf_small_cent[1] - (lon_diff / 2),
                          xmax = sf_small_cent[1] + (lon_diff / 2),
                          ymin = sf_small_cent[2] - (lat_diff / 2),
                          ymax = sf_small_cent[2] + (lat_diff / 2)))) %>%
  st_as_sf(crs = st_crs(sf_small))

And finally, plot the result. I have added a patchwork plot for side-by-side comparison, but the equivalent tmap code (see below) was tested and it produces your desired result.
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = bb, colour = NA, fill = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = sf_small) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))

p + ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = sf_large) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))


tmap code:
p <- tm_shape(sf_small, bbox = bb) + 
  tm_borders() + 
  tm_layout(frame = F)
tmap_save(p, "sf_small.png",height = 11.27, width = 14.69)

p <- tm_shape(sf_large) + 
  tm_borders() + 
  tm_layout(frame = F)
tmap_save(p, "sf_large.png",height = 11.27, width = 14.69)

